# How to store an array of structs inside anonymous member?

Tags: c, struct, c99

I have an set of structs that I want to store inside an anonymous member struct. Each small struct looks like this:

```
static struct {
    uint16_t buf[256];
} bufData[8];
```

I know for a fact it will only have 8 elements. I want to include this inside another struct, as such:

```
static struct {
    int size;
    // I am not sure how to proceed
    //char * bufData;
    //struct * bufData;
} Table[MAX_FILES];
```

The data is currently being entered as such:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        loadData(i,bufData[i].buf);
        printf("%s\n", bufData[i].buf); // This works
    }
```

and I would like to store this in the `j`th element of Table, like Table[j].bufData. Currently I've tried

```
memset(bufData, 0, sizeof(bufData));
Table[j].size = 256;
Table[j].bufData = &bufData;
```

and then unpackaging it, but it doesn't work.

```
char * test = Table[j].bufData;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", test[i].buf);
}
```

I think I've horribly mangled this one and I need some help untangling it!

Comment: how does the decl. look for bufData, is it a global variable? heap? stack?

Comment: it's a stack element that's unique for every Table[j] struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `bufData` is a structure, you should store it as a `bufData` pointer (not a `char` pointer), or simply as an array of `bufData`:

```
struct BufData /* this declares a type, not a variable */
{
    uint16_t buf[256];
};
```

option 1:

```
static struct 
{
    int size;
    struct BufData* myBufData;
} Table[MAX_FILES];
```

option 2:

```
static struct 
{
    int size;
    struct BufData myBufData[8];
} Table[MAX_FILES];
```

edit:
when declaring a struct, don't confuse declaring a type:

```
struct aStruct
{
...
};
```

with declaring a variable with an unnamed structure type:

```
struct 
{
...
} aVariable;
```

with declaring both a type and a variable wof that type:

```
struct aStruct
{
...
} aVariable;
```

Comment: It gives me `test.c:120:22: error: 'struct <anonymous>' has no member named 'bufData'` for both options (and I checked the syntax).

Comment: So I go with declaring both type and variable and the container struct Table is complaining that `tests.c:44:19: error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token` ...

Comment: I can't seem to access `Table[j].myBufData[i].buf` to store data, like         `memcpy(Table[j].myBufData[i].buf, buf, SOME_SIZE)` -- am I missing something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8253/discussion-between-rio-and-vulkanino)